# Htaccess redirects with parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to migrate a shop to another system, and would like to redirect my directories.

E.g. [www.oldshop.eu/stuff](http://www.oldshop.eu/stuff) to [www.newshop.eu/stuff/](http://www.newshop.eu/stuff/)

That I do by using

redirect 301 /stuff/ [www.newshop.eu/stuff/](http://www.newshop.eu/stuff/)

That works well, however my current shop has pages of the directories indexed, like:

[www.oldshop.eu/stuff/?p=2](http://www.oldshop.eu/stuff/?p=2)

That I dont want to transfer to the newshop, however I can see on search console that this is being done. Seems my redirect takes everything after the /stuff/ and just putting it over?!

How can i avoid this so that all url with ?p= or other parameters are being avoided?

Br. Brian

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rewriting module here:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?stuff/?$ https://new.example.com/stuff/ [QSD,R=301,L]
```

PS: It is a good idea to start out using a `R=302` *temporary* redirection and only change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as desired. That prevents nasty caching issues on the client side.